# Filling Up DropDown in Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to fill up my dropdown menu by a series of queries that I make, automatically whenever the page loads. Whenever I choose a value in the dropdown and I press a button, it goes back to the first index, so I'd like to know if there is anyway to prevent this problem:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Functions.username = "1"; // This is just to get rid of my login screen for testing puposes
    DropDownList1.Items.Clear();

    Functions.moduledatelister();
    for (int i = 0; i <= Functions.moduledatelist.Count-1; i++) {
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(Functions.moduledatelist.ElementAt(i));
    }

}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = Functions.DATES.ElementAt(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex).ToString();
}
```

after the button is pressed the index goes back to 0 and the label shows the value for the first item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can prevent it by using the [`IsPostBack` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx). You should databind your `DropDownList` only on the initial load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // DataBindDropDown();
    }
}
```

The state is maintained via `ViewState` by default, so no need to reload all items again on every postback. You would also prevent events from being triggered if you load the datasource again.

Answer (score 1):

in Page_Load check if it is a post back. To see why IsPostBack is needed and handle possible similar issues you need a good understanding of [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
        return;

    Functions.username = "1"; // This is just to get rid of my login screen for testing puposes
    DropDownList1.Items.Clear();

    Functions.moduledatelister();
    for (int i = 0; i <= Functions.moduledatelist.Count-1; i++) {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(Functions.moduledatelist.ElementAt(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to deal with IsPostBack property of page class:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
    Functions.username = "1"; // This is just to get rid of my login screen for testing puposes
    DropDownList1.Items.Clear();

    Functions.moduledatelister();
    for (int i = 0; i <= Functions.moduledatelist.Count-1; i++) {
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(Functions.moduledatelist.ElementAt(i));
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `IsPostBack` method:

```
if(!IsPostBack)    
{    
  //enter your dropdownlist items add code here    
}
```